# Does the stress damage from Wish reduce temporary hit points?

Tags: dnd-5e, wish, damage-reduction, injury

The rules for [Temporary Hit Points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints) are described in the following fashion:

> Some spells and special abilities confer temporary hit points to a creature. Temporary hit points aren't actual hit points; they are a buffer against damage, **a pool of hit points that protect you from injury.**

(emphasis mine)

However, the [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell details stress as such:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell. **This damage can't be reduced or prevented in any way.**

(emphasis also mine)

I've been playing around with this one for quite a bit. While some might argue that using temp HP to nullify the stress damage qualifies as reducing it, others would say that they are *still* technically taking the damage, so the bonus HP should be able to absorb it. However, why leave it up to the DM when we can reach a consensus here instead?

My question is, according to RAW (above samples included): **does the stress damage from Wish reduce temporary hit points?**

Comment: Related: "[Can a wizard use False Life and Life Transference to heal someone else?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116604)"

Comment: Did you mean to ask "can Wish stress damage *be reduced by* temporary hit points?"  Your title asks whether taking Wish stress damage can reduce the amount of temp HP you have.  That's not a damage reduction, that's an HP reduction.  And your question seems to be about whether to interpret temp HP as a damage reduction or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Temporary hp do not *reduce or prevent* wish damage, they absorb it

The damage is necrotic damage that is different from normal damage in that it cannot *be reduced* or prevented. Reducing [according to the dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20reduce) means:

> make smaller or less in amount, degree, or size.

The damage *wish* deals is not *being reduced or prevented* by the temp hp. *Wish* still deals all the damage. Instead, the temporary hit points are reduced by the damage, thereby buffering the amount of damage to normal hit points. So **yes, the stress of *wish* reduces temporary hit points**.

Answer (score 17):

### The damage is no different from any other damage

It’s just damage so it works the same as being hit with a sword - temporary hp first.